# By given some conditions how to copy the cells in VBA coding for excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Both figure below shows how I want the cells and rows to be filled with the data shown the first figure. I had done with the code for first figure but not able to figure out how to write the code for the figure 2 or the output I want.

Here's the code for the figure 1-

```
   Dim i As Long ' i-rows
   Dim j As Long ' j- columns
  
   'n is total number of rows
   'm is total number of columns with title 0,1,2,3 only.

 For i = 2 To n 'data starts from row 2
     For j = 4 To m 'data starts column 4
         If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(1, j).Value Then
             Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
            Else: Cells(i, j).Value = ""
      End If
    Next j
  Next i
```

Now, I don't what to & how to do in the `Else: Cells(i,j).Value = ""` to get what I want.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change to the nested `For` loops can achieve the desired result.

```
Sub demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, n As Long
    m = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    n = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Range("D2:G" & m).ClearContents
    Dim sKey As String, bFlag As Boolean
    For j = 4 To n 'data starts column 4
        sKey = ""
        For i = 2 To m 'data starts from row 2
            If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(1, j).Value Then
                Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
                sKey = Cells(i, 3).Value
            Else
                If Cells(i, 2) >= Cells(i - 1, 2) Or Cells(i, 2) >= Cells(1, j) Then
                    Cells(i, j).Value = sKey
                Else
                    Cells(i, j).Value = ""
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, its correct and working but I did changes in the figure like- if cat number(Ex. B5) is greater than the next cat no. (Ex. B6) then there should be no copying (Ex. G6 is blank). Same goes with the F9 cell. It would be really helpful if you could edit your answer.

Comment: thx its working and good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rw As Long, col As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim vCat, vOff
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    i = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    j = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    For rw = 2 To i
        vCat = ws.Cells(rw, 2).Value
        For col = 4 To j
            With ws.Cells(rw, col)
                If ws.Cells(1, col) = vCat Then      'header match?
                   .Value = ws.Cells(rw, 3).Value
                Else
                    If rw > 2 Then  'no header match: fill from above if has a value
                        vOff = .Offset(-1).Value  'value above
                        If Len(vOff) > 0 Then .Value = vOff
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next col
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, its correct and working but I did changes in the figure like- if cat number(Ex. B5) is greater than the next cat no. (Ex. B6) then there should be no copying (Ex. G6 is blank). Same goes with the F9 cell. It would be really great if you could edit your answer.